# Why isn't my javascript Image() caching in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, google-chrome, caching

I implemented a javascript function that creates and caches an `Image()` object, allowing images to be preloaded into the browser. When the image finishes loading, it executes a callback function. Here is the code:

```
var sprite;
function preloadimage(src, callback) {
sprite = new Image();
sprite.onload = callback;
sprite.src = src;
}
```

Here is how I am calling the function:

```
preloadimage(src,function(){$('#mainimage').attr('src',sprite.src);});
```

For some reason, this bit of code runs fine on Internet Explorer, but doesn't seem to want to work on Chrome. When `preloadimage` is called on Chrome, `sprite` doesn't seem to be cached and changing `#mainimage`'s `src` causes the browser to temporarily freeze for about half a second as it loads the new image. This is odd, since caching is still enabled on Chrome and other preloading methods, such as hiding the image directly inside of the html using:

```
<img style="position:fixed;height:1px;width:1px" src="imageiwanttopreload">
```

still work.

Is there any way to force Chrome to cache Image objects using jQuery/ Javascript? Does this have something to do with setting up `cache-control` and `max-age`? If so, how do I set it up locally? Currently I am not running any server like Apache and am simply running .html files off of my hard drive.

Comment: Is there any message on the debug console (ctrl+shift+j)?

Comment: Nope, there are no errors on console.

Comment: If you're running the files off of your harddrive, then caching becomes counter-productive. Chrome might not be caching the images for that reason. You should be using an object array to hold the cached images though.